How to import classes from a TypeScript file compiled with webpack?
Why doesn't the browser find the import? vscode recognizes "import {Animal} from './dist/output'". I have "animal.ts" file:
//animal.ts

export class Animal{
    species: string;
    breed: string;
    age: string;
    name: string;
    constructor(species: string, breed: string, age: string, name: string) {
        this.species = species;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
    info() {
        console.log("species: ", this.species);
        console.log("breed :", this.breed);
        console.log("age :", this.age);
        console.log("name :", this.name);
    }
}

In my terminal I have executed:
npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
npm install ts-loader typescript --save-dev
tsc --init
npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
the webpack.config.js is:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './animal.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'output.js', 
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
};

The 'output.js' file is:
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
    /******/    "use strict";
    var __webpack_exports__ = {};
    // This entry need to be wrapped in an IIFE because it uses a non-standard name for the exports (exports).
    (() => {
    var exports = __webpack_exports__;
    /*!*******************!*\
      !*** ./animal.ts ***!
      \*******************/
    
    //animal.ts
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", ({ value: true }));
    exports.Animal = void 0;
    class Animal {
        constructor(species, breed, age, name) {
            this.species = species;
            this.breed = breed;
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }
        info() {
            console.log("species: ", this.species);
            console.log("breed :", this.breed);
            console.log("age :", this.age);
            console.log("name :", this.name);
        }
    }
    exports.Animal = Animal;
    
    })();
    
    /******/ })()
    ;
    //# sourceMappingURL=output.js.map

And I have made the following files:
// myScript.js

import {Animal} from './dist/output'

const animal= new Animal('dog', 'German Shepherd', '3 years old', 'Bobby');
animal.info();

and the "index.html" is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Question</title>
    <script type="module" src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My question</h1>
</body>
</html>

When I load the page in the browser the console says: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './dist/output' does not provide an export named 'Animal' (at myScript.js:3:9).
